# How to get a objects age inside a vector?

Tags: c++, object, vector

I have a vector which stores `Student` objects

```
std::vector<Student> vec;
```

The `Student` has been initialized already

```
Student(std::string nameIs, int ageIs) : name(nameIs), age(ageIs){}
```

The objects are placed into the vector as shown below

```
Student a;
a.addStudent(Student("john" , 24));
a.addStudent(Student("Sam" , 23));
a.addStudent(Student("Bob" , 28));
```

I want to get the second object inside the vector and I want to get its age. I have a `getAge()` method already. I'm very new to C++ so I'm getting confused on the concept. How do I return the `a` object that's inside a `vector` and then check what its `age` is?

Comment: what is classA?

Comment: Vectors can be indexed like arrays. And just like arrays the indexes are zero-based, which means the second element will have the index `1`.

Comment: If you are properly doing push_back, then to get the student object you can use vec[1]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. A lot of creativity is need to put your snippets together into a working code, dont let us guess, but show us your code

Comment: apologies Oblivion, it was a typo which has been corrected

Comment: what would the type of my variable be if i assign it to vec[i]?

Comment: Is `vec[0].getAge()` not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get the second object inside the vector and I want to get its age... How do I return the a object that's inside a vector and then check what its age is?

Like a plain C-style array, [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has a 0-indexed [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) defined, which returns a reference to an element at a given index, eg:

```
int age = vec[1].getAge();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer : It is exactly the same as how you'd read "Age" from a object of "Student".

Longer Version : 
`a.addStudent(Student("john" , 24))` actually calls the constructor of the "Student" class, and what you're adding is an object of the Student class, not directly the age and name. So when you retrieve things from this vector that stores this object - you get an object of "Student" class. And to read "age" from this object you can use either class methods, or if it has pubic data members for age, you can read it directly using `object_name.age` (i.e vec[1].age in your case since you need the second item in the list).

If you have a method that directly returns the age like the "getAge" you mentioned - it should likely be doing the same.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/constructors-c/